# Anything wrong with using windows-1252 instead of UTF-8

Tags: html, oracle, encoding, utf-8, coldfusion

I have a test site that has been using windows-1252 all along.  They do need/use some symbols like the square root symbol.  And they have no need to display in another language other than English.  I was recently asked to switch it to UTF-8 because of some security concerns.  After I changed it to UTF-8 the square roots and other symbols (which are being pulled out of an Oracle DB and passed through ColdFusion) would appear fine on the resulting web page.  However, if I saved the document again (post to DB, page refreshes) the symbols transformed into strange characters.  If I saved again even more strange characters would appear.  So...

1. If I don't need anything other than English is there anything wrong with sticking to windows-1252?  Any security/hacking issues?
2. Are there any implications of NOT using UTF-8 if you are using
   HTML5 (since that is the default encoding for HTML5)?
3. If its recommended that I should switch to UTF-8, how do I get the currently
   stored square root symbols (and other symbols) to work?

I've already read all these pages, still having a little trouble grasping it all.  Hoping someone here and help clarify for me.  Thanks!

1. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Canonicalization,_locale_and_Unicode
2. **Excellent description of how UTF-8 came about, why it’s awesome, and the problems it solves…**
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4
3. http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings  “Use UTF-8, if you can”.  “In fact the HTML5 specification draft currently says "Authors are encouraged to use UTF-8. Conformance checkers may advise authors against using legacy encodings. Authoring tools should default to using UTF-8 for newly-created documents."”
4. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp “For HTML5, the default character encoding is UTF-8.”
5. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

*** * * UPDATE * * ***

I appreciate all that help so far to make this easier to understand.  **I'll simplify the original 3 questions so hopefully a clear answer can be reached**, so here it is: The customer doesn't need support for other languages, they will be using some HTML5 tags and a TON of JSON/XML traffic sent back and forth via jQuery.ajax(). Given that info, from a security standpoint, is there anything wrong with keeping the database set to `NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8MSWIN1252` and the webpages set to `<CFHEADER NAME="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=windows-1252">`?  Thank you.

Here is another question that is a slight spin off from this one: [Why am I able to use a character that's not part of a charset (windows-1252)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501300/why-am-i-able-to-use-a-character-thats-not-part-of-a-charset-windows-1252).

Comment: There's a lot of FUD and misinformation about character sets and encodings. Although there are security issues with some encodings (e.g. UTF-7), WIN-1252 isn't one of them. And w3schools is wrong again, UTF-8 is not "the default encoding for HTML5". The default encoding for HTML5 is not a simple matter.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 1252 is one of the many many fixed size character sets. Mac has its own set. there are a few ISO for various parts of the Europe and for some other parts of the world. Most of them have slight variations.

The good point is that you have a fixed-size character, meaning 1 character = 1 byte no matter what.

The bad points are:

- Some people may not have your encoding installed
- Some people may use a slightly different encoding, resulting in very few issues, not obvious to see, but very ugly on the long run
- You can only support a few languages

That include any citation you would like to make. In windows-1252 you can't display russian, greek, polish ...

UTF-8 is the standard encoding for unicode representation on 1+ bytes. It can represent a very large majority of the characters you may encounter, although it is designed for latin-based languages, as other languages take more storage space.

It in used in XML, JSON, and most types of web services you may find. It is a good default when you don't know what encoding to use. It allows to limit the number of encoding issues, such as "I though you were in Latin-1 / No, I was using latin-9, but then this guy on mac used Roman". If you have more than 1 people working on the content of the website, they may have different encodings on their plateforme, and therefore your content may be messed up at some point.

UTF-8 is, as far as I know, the only way to easily standardize the encoding used between people without discussion.

Typical example is, if your website is encoded in windows1252, and the new dev has a mac, you'll probably be in trouble.

Comment: "It in used in XML, JSON, and most types of web services you may find."  This customers site sends many JSON strings back and forth and there hasn't been issues with windows-1252.  But yes, I think I understand the different platform issue.  I'd like to figure out how to test that.  I have access to a Mac.  Can you think of some characters I can submit on each that would give different results?

Comment: omg. you are using json with windows-1252? that's an insidious bug waiting to happen. see, json specifies that it can contain any Unicode character. Most of which don't have a mapping in windows-1252. (most accented characters, anything danish, spanish maybe...)

Comment: Also, from json.org : `The character encoding of JSON text is always Unicode. UTF-8 is the only encoding that makes sense on the wire, but UTF-16 and UTF-32 are also permitted.`

Comment: Well, to be more specific, the JSON is made and posted using jQuery.serialize().  And all the JSON that I send back is thoroughly cleaned through a jsonSafe() function.  In that function we only allow [A-Z][a-z] then these characters are converted to the \u00 equivalent: asc(10), asc(13), and asc(32) thru asc(255). ALL other chars are ignored and not sent to the browser.  That's safe, would you agree?

Comment: And the JSON I send after it is serialized is done via jQuery.ajax and it's default contentType is UTF-8 which I do not alter.  So I'm sure the JSON is being transmitted as UTF-8 (see comment above for how I send JSON back).  It's the webpage that is set to windows-1252.

Comment: well, that another argument for utf-8. mixing content types is very error prone.

Comment: If a server side jsonSafe() function is removing characters outside of  then windows-1252 than you are not mixing types. Yes JSON is supposed to be utf enoded--when you need to transmit a mulit-byte character.   Also, for ajax requests, if you `Chrome Inspcect Element` and look at the network tab, the request is `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which prevents mixing of charsets.  Als the response will be `Content-Type:text/xml; charset=WINDOWS-1252`.

Answer (score 2):

You claim that Windows-1252 offers everything you need but the √ symbol is a [counter-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501300/why-am-i-able-to-use-a-character-thats-not-part-of-a-charset-windows-1252). You must be using one of these tricks:

- HTML entities: `&radic;`, `&#8730;` or similar
- Print another character and [change the font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_%28typeface%29)

In either case, your solution is not portable: stuff will only display correctly in a properly configured web browser. Everything else (database, JavaScript, text files, plain text e-mail messages...) will not contain the real data.

Additionally, JSON's only encoding is UTF-8. JavaScript will normally make the conversions for you but you must ensure that all your tool-chain behaves similarly.

So to answer your main question: there's nothing *wrong* in using Windows-1252 if that's all you need. The problem is that you already need more than it can offer.

As about your problems with UTF-8, it's obvious that UTF-8 is a full Unicode encoding so it does meet all the requirements. (Not being able to make it work can your reason to dump it but it isn't a technical reason.) My guess is that, since your current data doesn't have actual square root symbols, switching encodings breaks the trick you were using. You need to:

1. Find out what current data looks like
2. Run a one-time search and replace

Comment: The reason not to dump it is because of the huge task of converting many many huge Oracle databases. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011. Until then I just have to keep coding hacks for the certain characters. I have the hacks for displaying those chars in a function so if the day comes when we can switch my end of the job will be cake. I was told not using UTF-8 was a security risk (they didn't go into details why) that is what started this question. I still don't see why they would say that. Thanks for your contribution to this questions. +1

Answer (score 0):

What char set is the web server encoding?

Try changing the web server to utf8.  In apache.config:

```
 AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware the webserver plays a role in this, and even the DB has it's charset to consider as well.  I remember reading they must all be in sync or the same charset?  Is that correct?

Comment: Well, if the web server is sending back a fixed byte charset, it will send the html char for certain characters instead of the multi-byte equivalent.  So things can get messed up.