# Why am I able to use a character that's not part of a charset (windows-1252)?

Tags: oracle, encoding, coldfusion, character-encoding, windows-1252

I'm looking for a little help in understanding how charsets work.  This question is a continuation from [Anything wrong with using windows-1252 instead of UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490197/anything-wrong-with-using-windows-1252-instead-of-utf-8)

I have a test ColdFusion site using...

```
<CFHEADER NAME="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
```

and a test Oracle DB using...

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16
```

According to the windows-1252 charset there is no square root symbol (alt+251): √  But I can type that into a field on a webpage form, save it to the DB, query it and show it on the screen again just fine.  When it's in the DB it's stored as: `&#8730;`.  How can I enter that, store it, query and show it if it's not even part of the charset?  According to the charset, decimal 251 is this: `Hex:FB | û | 00FB | LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX`

Comment: Are you saying that in the database, the character is being stored as a 7 byte escape code?

Comment: Yes.  When I select that column in TOAD that is what it shows.  I haven't tried it from command line.  Are you thinking that just might be how TOAD is showing it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really using characters outside of the page and database's charset.

Because the page is windows-1252 encoded, if you enter Alt+251 into a form field and then post the data, the browser says:

```
"Hey this char is not apart of windows-1252 and I need to only send back data
 which is in windows-1252, so I will do the best I can and send back the 
 html character code of char &#8730;  -- oh well, I wish I could send back
 1 character, since I cannot I will send back 7."
```

And if you notice, this is 7 different characters which are in the windows-1252 charset.

Had the page been encoded with a multibyte charset, the browser would send back something which is considered 1 character.

So how can you query it?

```
 select * from tab where field like '%&#8730;%'
```

What you have is the html character of the square root symbol: https://www.google.com/#q=html+character+codes

### Update:

Here is a very good article explaining what is happening:  http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html

```
 "...once you start adding characters outside of your encoding... 
 [the browser might] replace the character with a character entity reference...."
```

Also when you enter Alt+251 on a windows machine, it inserts the square root symbol which in Unicode it is U-221A.

Pressing Alt+251 is just a like a keyboard macro to insert Unicode it is U-221A.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, but why doesn't `Alt+251` insert a `Hex:FB | û | 00FB | LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX` since that is the character at that position in the charset?

Comment: browsers will automatically hop up to sending utf-8 values given the slightest provocation in my experience. The HTML spec says they ought to then send a content-type header of 'text/plain; charset: utf-8 but they don't. In your test site above, if you HTML escape the content on the way out of the database when displaying it in HTML or a form field's value, it'll then break, as the escaping will escape the ampersand in the encoded value.

Comment: Ok, so you guys are saying regardless of my charset, I can still send, save, and re-query any possible character?  If so, then what's the point of even defining a charset if they will all work anyways? (I'm not at my PC to try other unicode chars but will do more testing tomorrow).  And on the way out of the DB it's being shown in a textarea, and displays the square root symbol correctly.  I haven't tried displaying it as text coming out of the DB.  To protect against XSS, when displaying as text I'm calling the ColdFusion esapi encodeforhtml. I'll test that tomorrow as well.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @gfrobenius, not necessarily...it is working with the square root symbol because there is an html character entity for the square root.  I do not know what happens in all cases. Hopefully someone can lend more insight.