# Custom google font error in HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I have a [blog](http://mohitmishra.tk/how-to-get-a-verified-twitter-account.html#overlay) where I use custom fonts from Google Fonts in each and every text of the `<body>` element, but whenever there is an inverted comma or a double inverted comma in my text, it is not shown as it should be - it is replaced by an unknown character.

I had even looked into the font and there is the character support for the inverted commas.

Comment: Did you copy paste content from word document?

Comment: If you blog is written in a popular cms you should search for a plugin that will add you that font for your blog. Copy pasting is not a good idea, just write your text and selected the necessary font from your editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with your font.

If you look at the source code you will see the characters already are broken there:

[image: screenshot of sourcecode]

This rather is a problem of your encoding. Your site is UTF-8, but the characters seem to be non-UTF-8. You either need to use UTF-8 characters or change the encoding of your site. (1st option is preferable)
If you change the site encoding to Windows-1252 (which is automatically suggested by Chrome based on the content) everything seems fine:

[image]

The question is how did you create this text? Maybe in Word and then copy and pasted? Or is your blog backend not UTF-8?

Also note there are two different characters: `’`vs `´`.

Comment: thanx for the help, i'll follow the first step.

Comment: Would changing the site encoding to Windows-1252 create any other problem as my site is hosted on linux server?

Comment: This is not a matter of the operating system used behind your blog. I highly doubt it would cause server side issues. But I would not suggest to use anything other than UTF-8. It is more or less the standard today. UTF-8 has a very wide spectrum of characters to display. If you'd ever wanted to display characters from other languages or special chars, with UTF-8 you can - without using cryptic `&whatever;` entities. Windows-1252 is limited to latin characters. I suggest you rather look into storing your content as UTF-8.

Comment: But Windows-1252 still would work. According to Wikipedia 0.9% of all websites use this charset: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 there also is a list of contained characters. If you chose this charset make sure you do not ever use any other than those chars in your content.

Comment: Also this question might be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490197/anything-wrong-with-using-windows-1252-instead-of-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

It's a special character. Please check below example

```
if you want to write "Don't"  than you have to use "don&rsquo;t"
if you want to write in double quote "highly sought users"  than you have to use &ldquo;highly sought users&rdquo;
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the special characters appears when you copy the text from other sources like MS word. This can be solved by manually entering inverted commas while entering or modifying in the database.